# how to get dataframes in list with grepl in r

Tags: r

I have dataframes names such as following

```
SS-VI-DPR 01.11.2016.
01.11.2016 -DPR SS1
DPR SS-II ( 01.11.2016 )
DPR SS IX 01.11.2016
RTY 01.45.3333
```

I want to get all the dataframes in list which contains `DPR SS` I am doing following but it does not work with all the situations

```
list_df <- lapply(ls(pattern="DPR SS+"), function(x) get(x))
```

Above code is able to match only 2 dataframes `DPR SS-II ( 01.11.2016 ),
    DPR SS IX 01.11.2016`

First two dataframes also needs to be matched.

Comment: Use `mget`: `list_df <- mget(ls(pattern="DPR SS+'))`. As a bonus, this will return a named list. You're expression will match 2, 3, and 4 in your example. If only 3 and 4 are desired, use "^DPR SS".

Comment: does `ls(pattern="DPR SS+")` find all the data frames you wish to put in the list?

Comment: It does not find all the dataframes. It only finds `DPR SS-II ( 01.11.2016 ),
DPR SS IX 01.11.2016` and not able to find `SS-VI-DPR 01.11.2016.,
01.11.2016 -DPR SS1`

Comment: I want to match `1,2,3 and 4`

Comment: Then your regular expression is insufficient. One method would be to use two `grepl` calls and combine them with `&` like `myVec <- grepl("DPR", ls(), fixed=TRUE) & grepl("SS", ls(), fixed=TRUE)` then `list_df <- mget(ls()[myVec])`. In one call, `myVec <- grepl("(DPR|SS)", ls())` should work.